# Topography data to elevation raster

Tags: qgis, dem, interpolation

In a previous question ([convert-xyz-points-to-topography-and-calculate-mean-slope](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188653/convert-xyz-points-to-topography-and-calculate-mean-slope)), I asked how to interpolate point elevation data to a raster in order to measure slope. Thus I use the Raster > Interpolation tool, and create the raster with TIN method, grid 300x300.

This works, however when I calculate slope (raster->Analysis -> DEM) it gets awful.

[image: Elevation raster]
[image: Slope raster]

I have few points, but I know some softwares such as Surfer provide tools to obtain a quite smooth surface by resampling.

Is that possible in QGIS? Do I need to resample the created raster? Or is there another way to get more "continuous" slope values ?

Comment: Is it possible to obtain contours, or even create contours from your point data?  then try interpolating from the contour lines.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of the best answer to this at the moment, but I can explain why you're getting that result. I think this is probably more suited to [Kriging](http://www.dmcsee.org/uploads/file/337_4_saga_kriging_manual.pdf). As pierma says, this is available using SAGA (via processing)

The Slope tool is doing what it's supposed to. The reason for this output is that you're using a TIN.

A TIN is a mesh of triangular faces, joined at their edges. Each face is made of 3 [coplanar points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coplanarity), which is a fancy way of saying the face's surface is 'flat' - although it can be tilted. The angle of tilt is the slope. Any 3 points in space are coplanar, but you can't say the same about 4 or more.

By definition, slope measures the local slope at each pixel. That's why each pixel which forms a triangular face has the same value - they all lie on a plane with the same slope.

Answer (score 1):

This aspect come from TIN interpolation.
You can try others interpolation methods. You'll find more algorithms in the processing toolbox, especially the SAGA tools.